# rhc setup failure - msg "OpenShift server is not responding correctly"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, installation, openshift, openshift-client-tools

Yesterday Aug 19 2014, I created a new scalable rails 4 application. Attempting to connect with rhc setup wizard tells me there is an error.  Here is the output with sensitive data replaced respectively:

Using [myaccount] to login to myapp-mydomain.rhcloud.com
The OpenShift server is not responding correctly.  Check that 'https://myapp-mydomain.rhcloud.com/broker/rest/api' is the correct URL for your server. The server may be offline or misconfigured.

Examining the app through openshift site, everything appears to be setup correctly.  I compared it to another app which I do have running and other than the scalable feature, all settings seem to be OK.

I did see a message from OpenShift a few days ago that they were having some trouble, I am wondering if this is still the case and my app did not create correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this command to use different account rhc setup --clean.

Answer (score 10):

When you run rhc setup you shouldn't change the value of the server.
Use the default server hostname `openshift.redhat.com`

Comment: Thanks.  It seems the DYN Dns was having maintanence yesterday.  A second try this morning has everything working as expected.